# closest multiple of double with offset java

Tags: java, math, rounding

I'm trying to get the closest multiple of 5.3 with an offset of 20.

ex.

- 21.3 would become 20
- 25.1 would become 25.3
- 29.4 would become 30.6

and so on.

I know how to get the closest multiple using

```
x = 5.3f*(Math.round(x/5.3))
```

but how do I adjust that for the offset?

Comment: Subtract the offset of 20 from X before you do your calculation, and add it back in after your calculation

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt post that as an answer and I shall upvote it.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ok, you're right that it has some use as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subtract the offset of 20 from X before you do your calculation, and add it back in after your calculation.

Like this:

```
x = 5.3f * Math.round((x - 20) / 5.3) + 20
//                       ^-- subtract ^-- add back in
```

Comment: ah, I was adding inside the round and subtracting it out. This makes more sense. Thanks